# android - how to calculate bitmaps coordinates in different screen if the value is from a server

Tags: android, socket.io, coordinates, screen-density

I'm developing a 2d multiplayer game using node.js as a server and Android as a client. Now, I scaled my bitmaps then multiply its width and height to the screen density to make it look the same on different devices/screens...

It's working. but my problem is its coordinates. When I open it to the preferred screen the x and y coordinates is fine, but when I open the game on an emulator with higher density the movement is slower and make it look like the image is in the wrong position but on the preferred screen its not.

I think the solution for this is to multiply the X or Y increment to screen density. but my calculations are retrieved from the server. X and Y coordinates are retrieved from the server as a whole.

Any ideas how can a calculate the coordinates that were retrieved from the server based on screen densities?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
Changed my bitmap scaling formula...
from

```
size * density
```

to

```
size * (target screen size/screen size)
```

then the formula for coordinates is

```
x or y * (target screen size/screen size)
```

got it from:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29750/fitting-android-game-to-different-screen-sizes